# Подзапрос в SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица в БД, которая содержит 3 иерархии по колонке ACCOUNT_CODE. Вот ссылка на скрин начала таблицы:  i.stack.imgur.com/wSlIm.png

А вот ссылка на первоначальный Excel источник: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ym5apeueajozzqw/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0.xlsx?dl=0

Данные в таблице в БД лежат точно также, только еще добавился ID.

Сначала идёт иерархия от CF-0000 до CE-0000, потом CE-0000 до SP-0000, потом от SP-0000 до конца таблицы. Поряядок гарантирован с помощью ID. НО, в каждой из этих иерархиий могут встречатся также чужеродные элементы, то есть в CF иерархии могут попадатся элементы иерархии CE и т.д.

Пытаюсь написать подзапрос, который сначала:

1) Извлечёт сначала одну иехрархию (строчка where не работает, только дял наглядности целей выборки) и позволит поработать с ней, что то типа:

```
SELECT *
FROM RealEstate_RiskEngine_LDR.dbo.LDR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY
WHERE ACCOUNT_CODE BETWEEN 'CF-0000' AND 'CE-0000'
```

2) Затем на основе дынных одной конкретной иерархии сделает другую выборку

```
With CTE as(

    select a.*
         , max(b.ID) PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
    from RealEstate_RiskEngine_LDR.dbo.LDR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY AS a
    left join RealEstate_RiskEngine_LDR.dbo.LDR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY AS b on
         b.ID < a.ID 
         and b.HIERARCHY_LEVEL < a.HIERARCHY_LEVEL
    Group by a.EXTRACTION_ID
            ,a.ID
            ,a.ACCOUNT_CODE
            ,a.ACCOUNT_NAME
            ,a.HIERARCHY_LEVEL
)    
select c.*,d.ID as child_id
from CTE c 
left join CTE d on c.ID = d.PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
ORDER BY ID
```

3) После того, как выбрали данные первой иерархии и что то с ними сделали, нужно выбрать данные второй, что то с ними сделать, а затем уже выбрать третью и опять что то с ней сделать. Всё.

Так вот: как совместить такие запросы друг с другом, что бы сначала выполнялся первый, а затем второй на основе данных, полученных с первого?

Comment: BETWEEN 'CF-0000' AND 'CE-0000'

Мне кажется, что первый запрос ничего не вернет, т.к. левая граница больше правой.

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko Да, по всей видимости я "затупил". Смотрите какая у меня ситуация: есть таблица в БД со строгим порядком следования. Есть колонка ACCOUNT_ID,  в которой друг за другом идут значения типа СF-0000 и т.д., скрин здесь: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSlIm.png

Так вот, мне нужно выбрать значения между, к примеру CF-0000 и CF-0028. Возможно ли сделать это используя BETWEEN?

Comment: Мне нужно достать всё между такой то и такой то ячейкой, без сравнения

Comment: Внёс изменения в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать не одно, а два табличных выражения?

```
;WITH data AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM RealEstate_RiskEngine_LDR.dbo.LDR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY
    WHERE ACCOUNT_CODE BETWEEN 'CF-0000' AND 'CE-0000'
)
,CTE as(
    select a.*
         , max(b.ID) PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
    from data AS a
    left join data AS b on ......
)
.....
```

В целом с таким же успехом, можно условия `where` добавить и в вашу cte,  а также в условия джойна:

```
select a.*
     , max(b.ID) PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
from RealEstate_RiskEngine_LDR.dbo.LDR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY AS a
left join RealEstate_RiskEngine_LDR.dbo.LDR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY AS b on
     b.ID < a.ID 
     and b.HIERARCHY_LEVEL < a.HIERARCHY_LEVEL
     and b.ACCOUNT_CODE BETWEEN 'CF-0000' AND 'CE-0000'
WHERE a.ACCOUNT_CODE BETWEEN 'CF-0000' AND 'CE-0000'
```

Или если вам надо заменить только таблицу `a`, то выполнить именно подзапрос, т.е. вместо

```
from RealEstate_RiskEngine_LDR.dbo.LDR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY AS a
```

написать

```
from (
    SELECT *
    FROM RealEstate_RiskEngine_LDR.dbo.LDR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY
    WHERE ACCOUNT_CODE BETWEEN 'CF-0000' AND 'CE-0000'
 ) as a
```

*зы: может вам задачу таки помогут решить оконные функции, а не самоджойны?*

Comment: Нет, и таблицу "b" также нужно заменить. 

Про оконные функции впервые услышал от вас, обязательно почитаю, спасибо.

Comment: там еще вариант может быть с подзапросом на `select max(id)`

Comment: Да, по всей видимости я "затупил". Смотрите какая у меня ситуация: есть таблица в БД со строгим порядком следования. Есть колонка ACCOUNT_ID, в которой друг за другом идут значения типа СF-0000 и т.д., скрин здесь: i.stack.imgur.com/wSlIm.png Так вот, мне нужно выбрать значения между, к примеру CF-0000 и CF-0028. Возможно ли сделать это используя BETWEEN? –

Comment: Мне нужно достать всё между такой то и такой то ячейкой, без сравнения

Comment: не совсем ясно. вам по скрину если надо выбрать только первые 3 строки, то нужно знать, порядок сортировки данных. То есть нужен какой то возрастающий id, далее выбрать этот id для обоих ячеек, и потом применит к id этот between

Comment: Нет, там есть 3 иерархии, каждая из которых начинается SP-0000, CF-0000, CE-0000. Мне нужно сначала выбрать всю иерархию между CF-0000 до CE-0000, потом CE-0000 до SP-0000, потом от SP-0000 до конца. То есть, в изначальном запросе на выборку по идее должны участвовать корневые элементы иерархий. ID не подходит в даном случае, как мне кажется.

Comment: ну если порядок иерархний такой (SP, CF, CE). то очевидно лексикографический `between` вам тут не поможет. используйте обычные операторы сравнения `ACCOUNT_CODE < 'CF-0000' AND account_code >='CE-0000'`

Comment: Хорошая идея, но  дело в том, что порядок другой (CF, CE, SP), и порядок важен. Кроме того, в одной иерархии могут повторятся элементы другой иерархии.

Comment: ну тогда вы меня окончательно запутали. внесите правку в ваш вопрос, и распишите с примерами что где и как.

Comment: Внёс изменения.